# Heap address Calculation

Tags: windows, memory, process, address, heap

I can see in the windbg disassembly the handle to the process heap on, allocated by the Windows (WINDOWS 10) for my process:

```
0:000> dt nt!_PEB 0106c000
ntdll!_PEB
   +0x000 InheritedAddressSpace : 0 ''
   +0x001 ReadImageFileExecOptions : 0 ''
   +0x002 BeingDebugged    : 0x1 ''
   +0x003 BitField         : 0x4 ''
   +0x003 ImageUsesLargePages : 0y0
   +0x003 IsProtectedProcess : 0y0
   +0x003 IsImageDynamicallyRelocated : 0y1
   +0x003 SkipPatchingUser32Forwarders : 0y0
   +0x003 IsPackagedProcess : 0y0
   +0x003 IsAppContainer   : 0y0
   +0x003 IsProtectedProcessLight : 0y0
   +0x003 IsLongPathAwareProcess : 0y0
   +0x004 Mutant           : 0xffffffff Void
   +0x008 ImageBaseAddress : 0x00840000 Void
   +0x00c Ldr              : 0x77a4ebe0 _PEB_LDR_DATA
   +0x010 ProcessParameters : 0x03b885e0 _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
   +0x014 SubSystemData    : (null) 
   +0x018 ProcessHeap      : 0x03b70000 Void
```

Now i want to examine the heap header, and apply the `dt !_HEAP` to the **ProcessHeap      : 0x03b70000**, but i can see that i get totaly invalid data in result. `!heap -s` gives me totally different results for the heap,

```
LFH Key                   : 0xd5ec6951
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
05e90000 00000002    1020      4   1020      2     1     1    0      0      
00ff0000 00001002      60      4     60      2     1     1    0      0
```

I understand, that the address where the heap header starts must be calculated  from this handle, **ProcessHeap      : 0x03b70000 Void** but i don't understand how it is calculated. its not a va, because 00840000 + 03b70000 != 05e90000 , so how to get from the heap handle, to the actual address of _HEAP structure header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the Page Heap verification, enabled by `Gflags`. I forgot about that, and the heap verifier was messing with the heap handles. When i disabled it, the handle at the PEB became valid.

Answer (score 2):

this is from win7 but that shouldn't matter much

**ProcessHeap From Peb of current Process**

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_PEB ProcessHeap @$proc 
   +0x018 ProcessHeap : 0x00430000 Void
```

heap Stat For the same

```
0:000> !heap -s @$proc->ProcessHeap


****************************************************************************
                                              NT HEAP STATS BELOW
****************************************************************************
NtGlobalFlag enables following debugging aids for new heaps:
    tail checking
    free checking
    validate parameters
LFH Key                   : 0x20cb0363
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
00430000 40000062    1024     24   1024      3     7     1    0      0      
00010000 40008060      64      4     64      2     1     1    0      0      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

HeapEntryStructure

```
0:000> dt nt!_Heap Entry.* @@(@$proc->ProcessHeap)
ntdll!_HEAP
   +0x000 Entry  : 
      +0x000 Size   : 0xda5a
      +0x002 Flags  : 0x5b '['
      +0x003 SmallTagIndex : 0xa9 ''
      +0x000 SubSegmentCode : 0xa95bda5a Void
      +0x004 PreviousSize : 0x2d79
      +0x006 SegmentOffset : 0 ''
      +0x006 LFHFlags : 0 ''
      +0x007 UnusedBytes : 0x1 ''
      +0x000 FunctionIndex : 0xda5a
      +0x002 ContextValue : 0xa95b
      +0x000 InterceptorValue : 0xa95bda5a
      +0x004 UnusedBytesLength : 0x2d79
      +0x006 EntryOffset : 0 ''
      +0x007 ExtendedBlockSignature : 0x1 ''
      +0x000 Code1  : 0xa95bda5a
      +0x004 Code2  : 0x2d79
      +0x006 Code3  : 0 ''
      +0x007 Code4  : 0x1 ''
      +0x000 AgregateCode : 0x01002d79`a95bda5a
```

Comment: This is really weird... for some reason my heaps doesnt match, i think this is because no CRT is used in application. I just created the default c console application and there is exactly 1 heap by `!heap -s @$proc->ProcessHeap` which does match `dt ntdll!_PEB ProcessHeap @$proc ` value. So crt does setup the heaps properly.. But isnt the process supposed to have the default heap header already created by the OS?

Comment: Nevermind, it was my fault. The Page heap verifier messed with the PEB's heap handle